# How to generate java classes for secured(https) soap web service using Apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I tried to generate web service classes from following url https://example.com:20008/mws-ws/services/TL_M3_PRSystem_Integration?wsdl this web service is working under a specific VPN.

I used apache cxf to generate java classes for this web service.

Then I got following error on cmd,

[image]

I could generate classes when I used an unsecured soap web service.

Anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: Do you have access to the VPN where the WS https is hosted? The WSDL page shows up when you try to open at browser (ie. Chrome)?

Comment: @RodrigoGomes : Yes , But I have to try several times to get it on browser.

Comment: Try to reach the page via postman and take a look at the response header when you don't have success at view the WSDL. This approach can give you a better idea of what is happening. You shouldn't have any interoperability to access the WDSL via browser, if you are connected to VPN. Make sure all your requests is going thru the VPN too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely signed by a self-signed (untrusted) certificate. The easiest way is to add this certificate to the `cacerts` java keystore or add it to a custom store and run `wsimport` with `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property set to the custom store.

1. Go to url in Chrome and use the Security tab in Dev tools to export the certificate to a file.
2. Use the `keystore` tool to import the certificate into `cacerts` keystore.

In the terminal:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias MyCustomCert -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file ~/path/to/saved/cert
```

or on Windows:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -import -alias MyCustomCert -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file C:\whereever\the\file\is
```

Make sure JAVA_HOME environment variable is defined and the command prompt you're using has permission to write to the `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got following exception once your steps are followed, 
   Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacerts (Access is denied)

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: @Barrier have a look at the answer again, I've adapted the command to Windows. Just make sure you run it in the elevated prompt or something like that so it has permissions to write to the keystore. Obviously %JAVA_HOME% variable needs to be defined too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot :)

Comment: I have completed your steps. But Still I am getting same error. What should I do ?

Comment: @Barrier can you post the content of the wsdl URL?

Comment: I am confusing in running wsimport with javax.net.ssl.trustStore